# Advanced Custom field datepicker data giving errors when used within custom wordpress post loop

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have custom wordpress front page where i want to show event dates in this format but here only post date shows..i want to replace it event date in the same format
[image]

here is my front page code

here is event post admin page
[image]

here is the advanced customfield page where i added events_field metabox field to show under each event post texteditor in admin
[image]

event loop before adding acf field

```
<?php
        
            $events = new WP_Query( array(
             'post_type' => 'event',
             'posts_per_page' => 2
            ));
            
            while($events->have_posts()){
                $events->the_post();
        ?>
          <div class="event-summary">
            <a class="event-summary__date t-center" href="#">
              <span class="event-summary__month"><?php the_time('M');?></span>
              <span class="event-summary__day"><?php the_time('d');?></span>
            </a>
            <div class="event-summary__content">
              <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
              <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(),15);?> <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="nu gray">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

problem is after i add advanced custom field name inside php DateTime object it shows error

event loop  after adding acf field

```
<?php
        
            $events = new WP_Query( array(
             'post_type' => 'event',
             'posts_per_page' => 2
            ));
            
            while($events->have_posts()){
                $events->the_post();
        ?>
          <div class="event-summary">
            <a class="event-summary__date t-center" href="#">
              <span class="event-summary__month"><?php the_field('event_date');
               // $eventDate  = new DateTime(get_field('event_date'));
               // echo $eventDate->format('M');        
              ?></span>
              <span class="event-summary__day"><?php the_time('d');?></span>
            </a>
            <div class="event-summary__content">
              <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
              <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(),15);?> <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="nu gray">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

this is the error i see

[image]

how ever if i just add this code within loop it shows the full date years months as put in acf field

```
the_field('event_date');
```

see screenshot

[image]
however i need to change the date format to match the theme like the first screenshot image i posted

after using EPB solution it works but only shows month number instead i need to show first three letters of month like JUN ,JUL

here is the current screenshot after using EPB code
[image]

and here is the new events loop code after using EPB solution

```
 <?php
        
            $events = new WP_Query( array(
             'post_type' => 'event',
             'posts_per_page' => 2
            ));
            
            while($events->have_posts()){
                $events->the_post();
        ?>
          <div class="event-summary">
            <a class="event-summary__date t-center" href="#">
              <span class="event-summary__month"><?php
     $date_string = get_field('event_date');
     $eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_string);
      echo $eventDate->format('m');
         ?></span>
              <span class="event-summary__day"><?php the_time('d');?></span>
            </a>
            <div class="event-summary__content">
              <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
              <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(),15);?> <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="nu gray">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

any help will be appreciated,thanks

Comment: Nice pictures, but you need to describe your problem better.

Comment: i want to show advanced custom field data within the custom event loop on the front page of my website..i have added few more admin pictures to give an idea whats the admin looks like and which field i want to show

Comment: Update your question to make it clear. Don't add another comments.

Comment: You are showing us a lot of code that doesn't seem to be related to the problem you are having. Please see how to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and edit the code so it is easier for us to help you with your question.

Comment: ok done. i have only added the event loop where the main problem is ..post updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks everyone i go this solved

here is the code

```
 <?php
            $today = date('Ymd');
            $events = new WP_Query( array(
             'post_type' => 'event',
             'posts_per_page' => 2,
             'meta_key'=> 'event_date',
             'orderby' =>'meta_value_num',
             'order'=>'ASC',
             'meta_query'=> array(
              array(
              'key'=>'event_date',
              'compare'=>'>=',
              'value'=>$today,
              'type'=>'numeric'
              )
             )
            ));
            
            while($events->have_posts()){
                $events->the_post();
        ?>
          <div class="event-summary">
            <a class="event-summary__date t-center" href="#">
              <span class="event-summary__month"><?php
     $date_string = get_field('event_date');
     $eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_string);
      echo $eventDate->format('M');
            
             ?></span>
              <span class="event-summary__day"><?php  echo $eventDate->format('d');?></span>
            </a>
            <div class="event-summary__content">
              <h5 class="event-summary__title headline headline--tiny"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
              <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(),15);?> <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="nu gray">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the date format you're using. That date format is ambiguous, so `DateTime` is failing to parse it correctly.

You could just change it to ISO format with `preg_replace` and use that when constructing your DateTime object. For example:

```
$iso = preg_replace('/([\d]{2})\/([\d]{2})\/([\d]{4})/', '$3-$2-$1', get_field('event_date'));
$dt = new DateTime($iso);
```

Edit: Or, better yet, use the `DateTime::createFromFormat` method format that let's you explicitly state the input format.

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', get_field('event_date'));
```

Comment: hello your code works but only partially ..i am looking to show first three letters of month but now it shows only month number..i have updated my post with screenshots of what i get..check first screenshot in my post to see the format i am looking for